# how do i control multiple div is using next/prev button with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

The display of the question will be 1 question at a time. there will also be a number indicator, to indicate the current question viewed.

I tried with only 2 questions for starters but the questions total will be more in the future.

Below are the colors for the indicators:

1. White - The user has not viewed the question.
2. Yellow - user viewed the question but decided to skip answering the question.
3. red - the current question that the user is viewing
4. green - user already answered the question
5. orange - user already answered the question and wanted to recheck(user can click the remark button to mark the question number to double check the answer before submit)

I got a hint to create a dynamic function to incorporate all the conditions, by the click of next/prev button. but I have no idea how to implement it for the nextprev button, I actually followed a sample at w3schools.

I really hoped that any of you experts can help me. I've been stuck here for days.

```js
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});



$(document).ready(function() {

  // Condition dah jawab soalan start
  $("input[name=answer]").change(function() {
    $('#q1').css('background-color', 'green');
  });

  $("input[name=answer2]").change(function() {
    $('#q2').css('background-color', 'green');
  });

  $("input[name=answer3]").change(function() {
    $('#q3').css('background-color', 'green');
  });
  //condition dah jawab soalan end



  //condition tekan button remark & jawab start
  $("#remark").click(function() {
    $('#q1').css('background-color', 'orange');
  });

  $("#remark2").click(function() {
    $('#q2').css('background-color', 'orange');
  });

  $("#remark3").click(function() {
    $('#q3').css('background-color', 'orange');
  });
  //condition tekan button remark & jawab end





  //condition skip soalan end





});

var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0) 
showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab



function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");

  x[n].style.display = "block";

  //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }
  if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Hantar";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Seterusnya";
  }
  //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
  fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  // This function will figure out which tab to display
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");

  // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
  if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
  // Hide the current tab:
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";

  // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  // if you have reached the end of the form...
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    // ... the form gets submitted:
    document.getElementById("borang_soalan").submit();
    return false;
  }
  // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
  showTab(currentTab);
}

function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status

}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
  // removes the "active" class of steps
  var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
  x[n].className += " active";
}
```

```css
.test {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.tab {
  display: none;
}


/* current active step */

.step.active {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="borang_soalan">

  <!-- Soalan 1 Start -->
  <div class="tab" id="soalan1">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <table class="table table-borderless">
          <td style="width:5%"><img src="images/bookmark-fill.svg" type="button" id="remark"></td>
          <td>1. 4 divided by 2 is ...</td>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card" id="jawapan">
      <div class="card-body">
        <input type="radio" id="ans1" name="answer" class="answer"> A. 5
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <input type="radio" id="ans2" name="answer" class="answer"> B. 2
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <input type="radio" id="ans3" name="answer" class="answer"> C. 1
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <input type="radio" id="ans4" name="answer" class="answer"> D. 0
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Soalan 1 End -->


  <!-- Soalan 2 Start -->
  <div class="tab" id="soalan2">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <table class="table table-borderless">
          <td style="width:5%"><img src="images/bookmark-fill.svg" type="button" id="remark2"></td>
          <td> 2. 2 + 2 equals</td>
        </table>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="card" id="jawapan">
      <div class="card-body">
        <input type="radio" id="ans5" name="answer2"> A. 2
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <input type="radio" id="ans6" name="answer2"> B. 5
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <input type="radio" id="ans7" name="answer2"> C. 6
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <input type="radio" id="ans8" name="answer2"> D. 7
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Soalan 2 End -->



  <br />
  <!-- Buttons -->
  <div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div style="float:right;">
      <button type="button" id="prevBtn" class="btn btn-info" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Sebelum</button>
      <button type="button" id="nextBtn" class="btn btn-info visited" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Seterusnya</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>

<!-- List No Soalan Start -->
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body" style="background-color:#f8f9fb;">
    <p style="color:blue;">Indikator Soalan</p>
    <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;" class="row">
      <div class="step rounded-circle border text-center test" id="q1">1</div>
      <div class="step rounded-circle border text-center test" id="q2">2</div>
      <div class="step rounded-circle border text-center test" id="q3">3</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- List No Soalan End-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this as a demo https://jsfiddle.net/ugonnaezema/brag1mv4/68/

You forgot to assign values to your radio buttons

```
<!-- Soalan 1 Start -->
  <div class="tab" id="soalan1">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <table class="table table-borderless">
          <td style="width:5%"><img src="images/bookmark-fill.svg" type="button" id="remark"></td>
          <td>1. 4 divided by 2 is ...</td>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card jawapan">
      <div class="card-body">
        <input type="radio" id="ans1" name="answer" class="answer" value="5"> A. 5
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <input type="radio" id="ans2" name="answer" class="answer" value="2"> B. 2
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <input type="radio" id="ans3" name="answer" class="answer" value="1"> C. 1
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <input type="radio" id="ans4" name="answer" class="answer" value="0"> D. 0
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Soalan 1 End -->


  <!-- Soalan 2 Start -->
  <div class="tab" id="soalan2">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <table class="table table-borderless">
          <td style="width:5%"><img src="images/bookmark-fill.svg" type="button" id="remark2"></td>
          <td> 2. 2 + 2 equals</td>
        </table>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="card jawapan">
      <div class="card-body">
        <input type="radio" id="ans5" name="answer2" value="2"> A. 2
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <input type="radio" id="ans6" name="answer2" value="5"> B. 5
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <input type="radio" id="ans7" name="answer2" value="6"> C. 6
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <input type="radio" id="ans8" name="answer2" value="7"> D. 7
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Soalan 2 End -->
```

Assign the `valid` variable outside the functions, update the `nextPrev(n)` and `validateForm()` functions with the code below:

```
var valid = true;

// find elements
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});



$(document).ready(function() {

  // Condition dah jawab soalan start
  $("input[name=answer]").change(function() {
    $('#q1').css('background-color', 'green');
  });

  $("input[name=answer2]").change(function() {
    $('#q2').css('background-color', 'green');
  });

  $("input[name=answer3]").change(function() {
    $('#q3').css('background-color', 'green');
  });
  //condition dah jawab soalan end



  //condition tekan button remark & jawab start
  $("#remark").click(function() {
    $('#q1').css('background-color', 'orange');
  });

  $("#remark2").click(function() {
    $('#q2').css('background-color', 'orange');
  });

  $("#remark3").click(function() {
    $('#q3').css('background-color', 'orange');
  });
  //condition tekan button remark & jawab end





  //condition skip soalan end





});

var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0) 
showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab



function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");

  x[n].style.display = "block";

  //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }
  if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Hantar";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Seterusnya";
  }
  //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
  fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  // This function will figure out which tab to display
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  var step = document.querySelectorAll('.step');

  // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
  if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) {
  step[currentTab].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  console.log("no answer");
  //return false;
  }
  
  if (n == -1) {
  step[currentTab - 1].style.backgroundColor = "orange";
  console.log("back");
  //return false;
  }
  // Hide the current tab:
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";

  // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  // if you have reached the end of the form...
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    // ... the form gets submitted:
    document.getElementById("borang_soalan").submit();
    return false;
  }
  // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
  showTab(currentTab);
}

function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  
  //$('.tab input:radio[name=answer]').change(function ()
  //{
    if ($('.tab input:radio[name=answer]').filter(':checked').length == 0) 
    {
        $('.tab input:radio[name=answer]').addClass("invalid");
      valid = false;
      console.log('false');
    }
    else
    {
        valid = true;
    }
  //});
  
  /* for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].checked == false) {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false
      console.log('false');
      valid = false;
    }
  } */
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status

}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
  // removes the "active" class of steps
  var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
  
  x[n].className += " active";
}
```

Comment: when I tried in the fiddle, it works, I added a few questions and it worked! but somehow when I tried the solution to my actual code, it does not work. but thank you @Ugonna !

Comment: I tried again this time, and it works. apparently I left something out. Thanks brother!

Comment: @atiq You are welcome. Please could you mark as the answer or upvote? Thanks